# Can't connect to FTP server through Apache + PHP webserver because of unrecognized PHP function (ftp_connect)

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll, ftp

the title is a bit self-explanatory, here are the details:

I'm running a webserver installed on a laptop with Windows 10 Pro x64, with **Apache 2.4** and **PHP 7.1.8** VC14 for x64 *(from Apache Lounge)* **installed as an Apache module** and running as Windows service, everything installed manually and separately.

*(I'm also using PHP for comunicating with a MySQL database, but this is out of the scope of this problem.)*

So everything has been perfect until I decided to incorporate a **FTP server** for offering a file library service through the website with FileZilla Server. *(In the same machine)*

---

The problem is, **PHP is unwilling to recognize the ftp_connect() PHP function**.

This is the PHP code I'm trying to run:

```
    try {

        // Create the connection.
        $conftp = ftp_connect('myhostname');

    } catch (Error $ex) {

        print nl2br("Error trying to connect to the ftp server:\n- " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
    }
```

- So; I did everything the official PHP installation manual said.
- I edited the corresponent php.ini configuration file and included the dynamic extension 'php_ftp.dll'.
- The library is the original file 'php_ftp.dll' that came with the installation.
- I also tried different PHP versions: PHP 7.1.6 and 7.0.22
- The PHP directory is on the Windows Environment PATH variable.
- I checked that the extensions directory ('ext') is being found by PHP because it detects when I remove another extension like 'php_pdo_mysql.dll'.
- Anyway also tried to put the library ('php_ftp.dll') on almost every directory I could think without success.
- I checked that the server supports it:

  ```
  C:\Nydus\php7>php -v
  PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2017 20:56:53) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
  Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

  C:\Nydus\php7>php --ri ftp

  ftp

  FTP support => enabled
  FTPS support => enabled
  ```
- I checked that the extension is being loaded correctly:

  ```
  C:\Nydus\php7>php -m
  [PHP Modules]
  bcmath
  calendar
  Core
  ctype
  curl
  date
  dom
  filter
  ftp
  gd
  hash
  iconv
  json
  libxml
  mbstring
  mcrypt
  mysqlnd
  pcre
  PDO
  pdo_mysql
  Phar
  readline
  Reflection
  session
  SimpleXML
  SPL
  standard
  tokenizer
  wddx
  xml
  xmlreader
  xmlwriter
  zip
  zlib

  [Zend Modules]
  ```
- Yes, I restarted the Apache service every time before checking it.
- I checked there is no bug about it in current PHP 7 distributions.
  https://bugs.php.net/index.php
- **I even ran the function successfully from the PHP executable!** and got the connection from the FTP Server:

  ```
  C:\Nydus\php7>php -r ftp_connect('myhostname');
  ```

[image showing ftp connection from filezilla server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDACL.png)

---

**So I have no clue why the function is not being recognized when I use it throught my website**, when I catch the error using try-catch, it gives me this error message: **"Call to undefined function ftp_connect()"**

**I would DEEPLY apreciate every bit of help you could throw on it**. This is the third day I do an extensive search of information but I am still stuck with this so I'm starting to get cremated.

If any of you need more information I will gladly cooperate.

Thank you for reading and for your time.

EDIT: Here is the error_log output when I try to use the ftp_function():

```
    [09-Aug-2017 19:05:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Nydus\php7\ext\php_curl.dll' - No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.
     in Unknown on line 0
    [09-Aug-2017 19:05:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Nydus\php7\ext\php_ftp.dll' - No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.
     in Unknown on line 0
    [09-Aug-2017 19:05:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Nydus\php7\ext\php_curl.dll' - No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.
     in Unknown on line 0
    [09-Aug-2017 19:05:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Nydus\php7\ext\php_ftp.dll' - No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.
     in Unknown on line 0
    [09-Aug-2017 19:05:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect() in C:\Nydus\Apache24\htdocs\conn_ftp.php:12
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\Nydus\Apache24\htdocs\profile.php(6): include_once()
    #1 {main}
      thrown in C:\Nydus\Apache24\htdocs\conn_ftp.php on line 12
```

EDIT2: I'm almost absolutely sure that PHP is for some reason *inherent to the extension or to php itself* unable to load php_curl and php_ftp, because **I gradually added the extensions I'm using and finds every other except those two**.

Well, I don't see what more could I test, so I will do the same project in a separate CentOs system installed in a partition, anyway if anyone knows what's happening here, please let me know.

EDIT3: Formated the entire system and redone everything, now it works.

The worst thing is that I will not know what was happening, but I had to do it because I've a dead line to meet.

*So maybe this post should be closed. Thanks for reading.*

Comment: Did you check `<?php phpinfo();`  in a browser window? Often there's two different INI files for CLI and Web-based.

Comment: Yes, checked it. And in "Loaded Configuration File" appears the route for the php.ini I configured.

Though in "Configuration File (php.ini) Path appears the route C:\Windows, I did now a search and don't found any php.ini related file.

Comment: Here is the whole phpinfo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xnazPx9OGRYXhoYmZ3S3BNSUE/view?usp=sharing

In the header there is information about what modules are loaded with the function get_loaded_extensions(), but now that I look closer there is nothing about the ftp module, should it appear there?

Comment: From what I can tell with mine, it should show up in its own section. Which means it did not load completely.

Comment: Makes sense, but even then I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, because I only know of one php.ini and it clearly has the ftp extension uncommented.

Maybe I had to do something else? I also set up the extension_dir correctly. Don't know what else could be.

Comment: I can only suggest checking the server logs to see if it's throwing any errors there.

Comment: I edited the main post and added the error log. By the way, many thanks for taking your time and helping me. It's strange because everytime I restart the apache service php tries to load those two extensions (curl and ftp) twice times. I'm starting to think is something about privileges, because the files are truly there. Will research further.